# MacBook Air screen problems after changing refresh rate

Tags: macbook-pro, display, mojave, screen

I was experimenting with [SwitchResX](https://www.madrau.com/) software, and thought it would be a good idea to change the refresh rate to 83 Hz. When I rebooted the laptop, the screen looked like this

[image: mac screen]

Is there any way to fix this? I am running macOS Mojave.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Try reversing the setting by following the instructions in [this](https://madrau.com/support/support/faq_files/Ive_defined_a_new_resolution_an.html) support article.

Comment: @Nimesh Neema Thanks for the article, but none of it worked for me. I cannot boot into single user mode, recovery mode, or safe mode.